# onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState and view state

Tags: android, android-activity, savestate

According to the documentation of onSaveInstanceState:

> The default implementation takes care of most of the UI per-instance state

and onRestoreInstanceState:

> The default implementation of this method performs a restore of any view state that had previously been frozen

I'm not sure exactly what that means.
Is it meant to mean that when returning after being killed and now restored, that the UI screen shown to the user is automatically restored with all its data?
If so, I am not seeing that.
All I get is an empty screen unless I do setContentView myself.

AM I misunderstanding the meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default implementation will work for every widget which ids are defined.
For example, If you have one EditText and if you will provide its id then system will save its value when Activity will be killed due to orientation and same and it will restore the EditText value when activity will be re-created.

**Edit**

If you have one base layout and if you are dynamically adding some views in the view hierarchy then you will have to handle the save state and restore state your self. also when your activity will be re-created then onCreate() method of the activity will be called so in this method first set all the addition views which you are creating and adding dynamically and then you can check the extra parameters with the intent which you are getting in the onCreate() method. This extra parameters are exactly same as you have adding extra parameters in the `onSaveInstanceState` method.

So implement like below.

```
int x = 10;
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("x", x);
}
```

And in onCreate method you can get this x parameters like below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xxx);

    if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("x")) {
        x = savedInstanceState.getInt("x");
    }
}
```

Comment: But does it restore the content view itself? Cos it isn't doing it for me. Maybe I am simply doing something wrong.

Comment: Try to create one demo app in which take one EditText and *provide its id* don't override the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods in your activity. Run your app type some text in EditText and change the orientation of the device/Emulator, Your activity will be re-created and the values of the EditText will be restored and you will see your entered text in the EditText

Comment: Ok. I now see where my problem was. I thought you didn't need to re-do the "setContentView". In our case we build most of the view dynamically by adding pre-expanded views into an existing one. We have a base XML layout and we expand layouts and put them in. This enables us to keep a standard look and feel and general layout (screen titles etc) without having to re-do it for each layout separately.

Comment: So it only saves the base original view and I must rebuild the added/replace views myself.

Comment: You have misunderstanding. When activity is re-created then its onCreate method will be called and in this method the setContentView(int) will be called that means the base layout also again being created. and also system will set its saved values to the widgets if widgets have unique id. Like wise in onCreate you set additional views so no need to deal with it. You just have to check the saved values and update widgets values if activity is re-created.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19467/discussion-between-theblitz-and-dharmendra)

Comment: @theblitz I have the same problem. What's the answer for your question: "So it only saves the base original view and I must rebuild the added/replace views myself. " ??

Comment: if my view is a library then i don't have any control on the activity , what to do in that case?